# Few question about client application to be networked

Tags: mysql, vb.net, network-programming

1. I have made a registration program. Making use of mysql database. Can I still use the traditional programming for client applications. If I want to network it. Do I have to modify the codes a little in order to make it work?

-Please enlighten me, I'm just a beginner. I don't have any idea on how this works. Do I have to install wampserver only in one computer?

I'm using visual studio 2008. Win forms to be exact.

Comment: A bit more detail needed here.... Is the IT you want to network the database OR the application? Given the correct connectString and a LAN, your application could be installed on many machines simultaneously and all operate correctly.

Comment: I'm thinking of the database only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's really no difference between using a mySQL database and a SQL Server or Oracle database for Windows Forms programming.

To connect to your mySQL database during development, you will need to download and install the [MySQL .Net Connector](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/) on your development PC.  Once you've referenced the MySql.Data DLL in your WinForms project, you can then use the MySql database classes to retrieve data:

```
string MyConString = "SERVER=localhost;" +
    "DATABASE=mydatabase;" +
    "UID=testuser;" +
    "PASSWORD=testpassword;";
MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(MyConString);
MySqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
MySqlDataReader Reader;
command.CommandText = "select * from databaseTable";
connection.Open();
Reader = command.ExecuteReader();
```

etc..

You will need to install mySQL server on a database server somewhere - one way to do this is indeed using [wampServer](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) (although it's a bit heavier than you really need - you definitely don't need Apache or PHP, although I guess phpMyAdmin is a good way to manage your mySQL database).  Either way, you'll probably just want one central database on a single server, so you'd just install wamp there.

Comment: can I install wampserver even if the computer is not a server?